# Text disappears after a second in Flashplayer 11

Tags: flash

I recently upgraded to flashplayer 11 and found that it made all the text on my buttons and dynamic text fields disappear.  I noticed that you can see it when it first load and then vanishes.  I can't find any documentation on this.  Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Haven't seen this - do you mean for your applications (you've built) or all Flash applications you load?  Is this TLF text?  Do you seen this from Flash Pro publish or only in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem, right now i'm developing a flash admin based on adobe cs5 component set.
In flash player 10 everthing is OK, in Flash Player 11 (Debug version) texts in components are disappearing after 1 sec.
I've tried this both with embedded and non-embedded arial font and result is the same. Flash components are not using TLF, just the normal native TextField-s.
My only suspect left is that i'm using some masks defined in flash (so not programatically by as3) and exactly those components who are masked have this strange disappearing text effect.

## Edit 1

After removing timeline masks, text behavior went normal, so my tip is to use masking with actionscript code: targetMC.mask = maskerSprite - not the timeline version.
Tutorial about masks in flash: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/

Answer (score -1):

You might be suffering from this Adobe Bug:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3096641

Comment: Consider expanding your answer with some excerpt from the referenced page. See [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for details why bare links are not considered good answers.